# Parsing XML: NullReferenceException for Variable Elements

Tags: c#, xml

I'm getting a text string from a website and parsing it into an XDocument. I'm looking to feed the value of certain elements into a very simple object (named NWSevent). My problem is that the original string changes and the XML tree varies; sometimes there are numerous events, up to 40, sometimes there is only one, and sometimes there is only one that does not have all the characteristics. If there are no alerts, then the "event" element has a title, but no areaDesc, summary, or severity.

I have two constructors for NWSevent, one takes in a single string, the other takes in four string arguments. I'm having trouble getting around a NullReferenceException. The if statement below can't do it because there is no value to compare. I'd appreciate any help.

```
    public static void ParseWeatherData(String xmlString)
    {
        String ticker = string.Empty;
        XDocument root = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

        XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
        XNamespace nsCap = XNamespace.Get("urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1");

        //get list of entry elements, set conditions for title, areaDesc, etc
        var xlist = root.Descendants(ns + "entry").Select(elem => new
        { //use first or default to deal with possiblity of null return
            Title = elem.Descendants(ns + "title").FirstOrDefault(),
            AreaDesc = elem.Descendants(nsCap + "areaDesc").FirstOrDefault(),
            Severity = elem.Descendants(nsCap + "severity").FirstOrDefault(),
            Summary = elem.Descendants(ns + "summary").FirstOrDefault()
        });

        foreach (var el in xlist)       //need to address null values when no alerts
        {
            if (el.AreaDesc.Value != null)      //causes yellow null ERROR; no value exists for el.areaDesc.value
            {
                String titleIn = el.Title.Value;
                String areaIn = el.AreaDesc.Value;
                String severityIn = el.Severity.Value;
                String summaryIn = el.Summary.Value;
                new Models.NWSevent(titleIn, areaIn, severityIn, summaryIn);
            }
            else
            {
                String titleIn = el.Title.Value;
                new Models.NWSevent(titleIn);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks to me like you need to check el.AreaDesc for null before trying to get the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarassing!  Props to Dweeberly for pointing it out.  I just need to change the if statement from

if (el.AreaDesc.Value != null){}

to if (el.AreaDesc != null){}